# Bizarre jQuery UI issue: a transient, "randomly" occurring undefined variable error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery UI tabs feature on my website. It worked great for several months. In recent weeks it developed the bizarre symptom of not loading the tabs occasionally, and producing this error:

```
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jQuery( "#tabs" ).tabs()')
    (anonymous function) (index.php, line 37)
    j (jquery-2.1.0.min.js, line 2)
    fireWith (jquery-2.1.0.min.js, line 2)
    ready (jquery-2.1.0.min.js, line 2)
    I (jquery-2.1.0.min.js, line 2)
```

It worked fine before, it tends to work fine now on Firefox, and it tends to fail on Safari and Chrome (though not always!).

Any ideas what could create this occasionally occurring problem?

For the record, browsers tested on OS X 10.9.2: 
Safari 7.0.4
Firefox 29.0.1
Chrome 35.0.1916.153

Comment: Has your jQuery version been changed recently?

Comment: Make sure you're not getting an error loading the `jquery-ui` library.

Comment: I haven't changed the jQuery version recently, I don't see any other Javascript error on the page.